# How to list hanging mpi jobs

Tags: mpi, jobs, mpich

I'm running some jobs using `mpiexec` (mpich2).
`mpiexec` process exits with nonzero status leaving some worker processes

I can print a list of running child jobs:

```
$ps aux | grep mpi
```

Is there another way to list running/hanging jobs?

Answer (score 0):

If MPI leaves around a zombie process (which is odd, this really shouldn't be happening), it will be named whatever the executable that you originally executed was called. So if you started your program with:

```
mpiexec -n 4 ./a.out
```

then you'll need to search for

```
ps aux | grep a.out
```

which will give you the list of all of those processes that are still hanging around. The reason that what you suggested won't usually work is that if the `mpirun` or `mpiexec` process has gone away (due to a crash or completion), you obviously can't keep searching for it. However, it's possible that the children will still be around for one reason or another.

Answer (score -1):

this may help you : ps aux | grep MPICH

Comment: Nothing started by MPICH actually says MPICH as the name of the process. They executable is called `mpiexec` or `mpirun`.